# how to run some suites using specific capability in Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, protractor

I have a website both for desktop browsers and mobile browsers, and obviously they have different UI. In my protractor config file, some suites need to be ran using plain(desktop) user agent, and some other suites need to be ran using mobile user agent.

I know there is a option called `multiCapabilities`:

```
multiCapabilities: [{
        'browserName': 'chrome'
    }, {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'chromeOptions': {
            'args':['--user-agent="iphone"']
        }
    }],
```

using config like this can run all the suites both on these two browsers(one for desktop, another for mobile), but I want to know is there a method that I can run some suites using first capabilities and run others using second one?

For example, can I manually set user agent is the specific Spec file using js code?

Comment: I think you can add `specs: []` inside multiCapabilities. https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/fbfc72bad15667990232bb9ff1da503e03d16230/spec/shardingConf.js#L29

Comment: @AndresD This should work, but what I want is suite 1,2,3 run on browser 1, suite 4,5 run on browser 2. This will make suite 1,2,3 also run on browser 2.

Comment: Can i ask why you want to do this ?

Comment: @gontard I want some e2e test running on desktop browser, and others running on mobile browser(using user agent to emulate), that's all I want. Now I write 2 config file for each, I'm asking is there a method to use only one config file.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from @AndresD's comment since I can't comment yet, why doesn't this work for you?

```
multiCapabilities: [{
  'browserName': 'chrome',
  specs: ['specsA_for_browser1.js', 'specsB_for_browser1.js']
}, {
  'browserName': 'chrome',
  'chromeOptions': {
    'args':['--user-agent="iphone"']
  },
  specs: ['specsA_for_browser2.js', 'specsB_for_browser2.js']
}],
```